# Python: negative TIMESTAMP convertion to human DATE

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

Suddenly ran into issue with this timestamp (which was hidden in JSON object):

```
-180835200000
```

Tried to extract standard timestamp with:

```
dt.strftime(dt.fromtimestamp(json.loads(res.text)['suggestions'][0]['data']['state']['actuality_date']/1000),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

But failed since the value is negative.

How do I convert this negative TIMESTAMP to human date ?

Comment: Whats the error ? `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-180835200000/1000)` works perfectly using Python3.9

Comment: Python3.7 get error - OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument. But this is easy to solve `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(abs(-180835200000/1000))`

Comment: Add to Unix epoch as timedelta if necessary: `datetime.datetime(1970,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-180835200000/1000)`

Comment: weird...but i doesnt work for me. I m using Anaconda with custom VirEnv

Answer (score 0):

The given time is a POSIX time (aka Epoch time or Unix time). It represents the number of seconds that have elapsed since the 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970, excluding leap seconds. [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

For your application, if the timestamp has a negative sign in front then it represents a time point before January 1, 1970. Make sure the time is in integer format and the following result is tested in Python 3.7.12;

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strftime(dt.fromtimestamp(-180835200000/1000),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

> Outputs (human readable)

```
1964-04-09
```

If you believe that the negative sign is a mistake in data, you can simply use abs() function which will output 1975-09-25.

Comment: Why does it have to be an integer?

Comment: Since the time represented in the JSON file is not in seconds format but in milliseconds format. That is the reason why the original code divides the time with 1000. If the timestamps is in String format, you will get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'" and even if you could manage it to divide, the datetime will yield "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)". The float is possible to input but there is no need for float numbers in milliseconds of POSIX time.